# Were 50% meat, 50% something else products ever predicted by sci-fi?

Tags: history-of, prediction

50% meat, 50% plant-based "meat" products are currently available for purchase. I'm fairly certain that "fake meat" of various forms was predicted by sci-fi before it was ever commercially produced. However, I'm wondering if the idea of partially meat and partially non-meat products made to resemble meat products was ever presented in fiction before such a thing was commercially available.

Comment: If anything has ever been predicted is a bit of a grey area into a list of works question which is off topic. Asking for the ___first___ time this happened in a sci-fi work though is perfectly on topic and would only take a small edit to change.

Comment: SOYLENT GREEN IS PEOPLE! IT'S PEOPLE!!!!

Comment: Many products made from ground meat already contain plant based stuff as a filler (German meatloaf contains breadcrumbs, although ideally not 50 percent). In fantasy, this is taken to an extreme in a scene in Terry Pratchett's "5th Elephant", where it is pointed out that "here [in the country of Uberwald] an Ank Morporkh Sausage  would not be considered a sausage" but "a loaf. Or a possibly a log". This alludes to shoddy manufacturing rather than culinary breakthroughs in meat replacement products (which I assume you are after), so I won't make it an answer.

Comment: Are you after pure meat substitutes, like fake beef?  What about something like vat meat, which is 100% cultured meat tissue?

Comment: Does this count? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ningyo

Comment: @DavidW, completely vat-grown would be Chicken Little from "Space Merchants", there is already a question for that. Completely artificial would probably be the Martian food in Lasswitz "Two Planets" (synthesized from Petrochemicals) in 1897. It's the 50/50 mix  that makes this question difficult.

Comment: @Everyone leaving comments: Your examples are all *far too late*. China has been making fake meat for well over [a thousand years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_analogue#History).

Comment: @Kevin, China is not science fiction. Also Tofu Seitan etc. is not a mix of meat and plants.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: The question says "before such a thing was commercially available."

Comment: @Kevin, point taken.